# end Kernel panic - not syncing - 22.10

Tags: boot, kernel, crash, bootloader, acpi

Hi im getting an error message on my Ubuntu (see image) which does not allow me to boot my laptop. I dont want to reformat since i will lose everything. Please help[image]

Comment: Try booting from flash stick and doing system restore.

Comment: And while you are booted from that flash stick is a great opportunity to back up your data. Having a fresh backup removes a lot of the stress.